# How to make quantized tflite support tf.pow function?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow-lite, quantization, hexagon-dsp

Because the original tf.pow function cannot be quatilized. So I want to adjust the implementation method of the pow function so that tflite can support the pow function.

The original method of Pow function is

```
Po = Pi ^ gamma
```

changed to

```
ln (Po) = gamma * ln (Pi)
```

so,

```
Po = exp ^ ( gamma * ln (Pi) )
```

In this way, the power function can be **replaced by exp function and ln function**.
Because **Taylor expansion only needs multiplication and addition** to calculate exp function and ln function, tflite provides multiplication and addition.

I just need the **range 0~1**. The range of **Taylor expansion of ln function (at x=1)** is as follows:
[image]

I need all **ranges less than 0**. So I tried the **exponential function of taylor expenditure** in the subsection, as follows:
[image]

I also tried **linear approximation** of exponential function.
[image]

I still can't speed up the model with both methods.

Can anyone help me?

> quantized tflite support function list:
> https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/f9bdcd6d9c714fc5dde232ba3b8b0a5128a07516/tensorflow/lite/delegates/hexagon

Comment: problem is with the speed of implementation or the results are not matching with pow function?.

Comment: @V.M It's speed.

Comment: In that case you can post your code, people can comment on how to improve it.